# 14.04:dpkg error processing package droidcam (--configure):

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

I have a problem in my Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed Droidcam and now I can't remove or install nothing because my droidcam is lock everything

please see below

```
    dpkg: error processing package droidcam (--configure):

    vitor@vitor-pc:~$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up droidcam (1.3-0ubuntu0) ...
    tar: *.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    dpkg: error processing package droidcam (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    droidcam
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This Doridcam lock every command

```
         vitor@vitor-pc:~$ LANG=C sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
         Reading package lists... Done
         Building dependency tree       
         Reading state information... Done
         Calculating upgrade... Done
         0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
         1 not fully installed or removed.
         After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
         Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
         Setting up droidcam (1.3-0ubuntu0) ...
         tar: *.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
         tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
         dpkg: error processing package droidcam (--configure):
          subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
         Errors were encountered while processing:
          droidcam
         E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where that package is from, but I'm guessing you have added some sort of PPA. It seems this package is broken, so I would recommend removing it and finding some other way to install it.

```
$ apt-get purge droidcam
```

That should let you use apt again.